# How to compare two JSON files without iterating through them using java

Tags: java, json

I have two JSON files which have a large amount of records(objects). One file has about 1200 records in it and the other has 600. I'm sorry that i couldn't post them here, but i want to compare both of them, and get back the records that are common. The trick here is that i can't iterate through them, as there are a large number of records and the tool which i'm using cannot support this. I'm posting my sample json below:

```
{"xyz":{"string":"hello"},"abc:{"string":"rts","event":"file","value":"100"}}   
{"xyz":{"string":"hello"},"thg{"Integer":"rts","event":"file","value":"100"}}
```

My question is whether any libraries are available where i can directly compare two JSON files using predifined methods. If no such libraries are available, can you give an optimal way to find the similar records such as "xyz" in the above example.

**I'm not supposed to use GSON as it is incompatible with the tool.**

Comment: If you're on linux, use diff file1 file2. There are also many utilities in Windows environment that do the same thing

Comment: What is the desired output of your example?

Comment: @CocoNess: As i have mentioned, I need to do it in java.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. "without iterating through them using java". 'Iterating' == false and 'Using Java' == true.   The logic of your  question's header isnt clear

Comment: Also, I dont understand why you cant use Iteration.

Comment: @CocoNess: There are about 8 JSON files with thousands of JSON records present in it. All the JSON file contents are merged together, and are sent to us. We have to compare a single output file with this merged file and retrieve similar records. So iterating through those records would take a lot of time, and the tool that i use would throw a timed out exception. So, I thought if there's any library that could decrease the time complexity then it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about libraries, but definitely the algorithm will involve first sorting both files and after that, yes, you should perform iteration and recordwise comparison. The general complexity would be O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at below link.

http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff/

This will compare two json contents.

Hope this is what you was looking for.